# How to trigger ng-dblclick with Watir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, angularjs, watir, watir-webdriver

Our development department is using AngularJS to build web applications.
And I'm looking into automated testing because it will save us a lot of time.

I found Watir to be very useful while testing... the thing is, it doesn't work very well with AngularJS.

Example:
We have a select multiple with items. These items all use ng-dblclick to trigger an action (creating a div).

I've tried to use:

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").select("Item 2")
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").fire_event("dblclick")
```

And

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").select("Item 2")
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").fire_event("ng-dblclick")
```

And

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").select("Item 2")
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").double_click
```

And

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").select("Item 2")
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").click
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").click
```

All without succes.

My questions are:
a. Is it even possible to double click on AngularJS ng-click/ng-dblclick enabled elements?
b. If so... how?

Thanks!

Comment: It would **really** help if you could link to a page with example HTML, or provide relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based the problem description, I am guessing that the ng-dblclick is actually on the list's options, rather than the list itself.

Try clicking the option itself:

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").option(:text, "Item 2").double_click
```

Comment: Hi Justin!

Thanks for your reply! With your help I got it to work:
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").option(:text, "Item 2").fire_event("dblclick")

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the .double_click from Justin's post to .fire_event("dblclick") made it to work!

```
browser.select_list(:class, "domain-list").option(:text, "Item 2").fire_event("dblclick")
```

Thanks Justin!